# Android BitmapFactory often returning null on Base64 decoded byte array

Tags: java, android, image, sockets, base64

I have a Java server on my PC using the infamous Robot class to capture screenshots, encode them to Base64 strings and then send them to an Android client over a Socket using a PrintWriter

The Android client reads the Base64 encoded strings, converts them back to byte arrays and then into Bitmap images for display in an ImageView.

The problem is that while this sometimes works as expected, often the BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray method will return null and hence render nothing to the ImageView.
Giving me a message in Logcat `D/skia﹕ --- decoder->decode returned false`

I can reproduce successful/unsuccessful decodes by changing what is displayed on the PC, it can be as simple as highlighting a line of onscreen text that will cause the decode to starting failing and un-highlighting will return it to succeeding.

When the decode has failed I have tried both comparing it to the string that was sent by the server (is always 100% the same) and validating the Base64 encode with an external tool [Base64 to Image Converter](http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter), which always shows a perfect image.

This happens on both a real device running Android 4.1 and an emulated device on Android 5.1

Have spent 2 days so far poring over SO and the internet in general looking for an answer but haven't found anything that quite fits my situation.

Why would BitmapFactory method be failing so often?
Or have I stuffed something up terribly in my client code?

**Android client code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Socket socket;
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 6666;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.2.5";
    private ImageView imgContainer;
    private Bitmap bitmapObj;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imgContainer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgContainer);
        new Thread(new ConnectionThread()).start();
    }

    private class ConnectionThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                // first line is garbage
                String inStr=in.readLine();
                //image receiver loop
                while((inStr = in.readLine()) != null){
                    // log shows string is always same length as the one sent
                    Log.d("IMGTHREAD", String.valueOf(inStr.length()));

                    byte[] img64 = Base64.decode(inStr, Base64.DEFAULT);

                    //Fails here, bitmapfactory decode often returns null? but not always
                     bitmapObj = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img64, 0, img64.length);

                        // update the imgContainer ImageView
                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                imgContainer.setImageBitmap(bitmapObj);
                            }
                        });

                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 'decodeByteArray method will return false'. Null you mean?

Comment: 'Why would BitmapFactory method be failing so often?'. Lack of memory.

Comment: @greenapps - Yes, null, fixed in question, thanks.  Memory usage is fairly small, the images themselves are only 200x200, and if the screen is something the decoder seemingly arbitrarily likes it will keep decoding successfully until i change what is displayed.